# Change selected option from table

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sorting

I want to filter my result.I want to sort table parameters by selecting option.

Here is my output
[image: My Output]

I wrote HTML code for this as shown below:

```
<div class ="sort">
  <dl class="vertical">
    <dt>
      <label for="sort" title="Sort"><strong>Sort</strong></label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();" size="1"  tabindex = "3">
        <option id="name" value="1">Name</option>
        <option id="size" value="2">Size</option>
        <option id="date" value="3">Date Modified</option>
      </select>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest to me how to get the output by selecting. Do I need to create object class ?

Comment: Do u have idea of ajax?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  I have also made your image inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can get select values by using jquery:

```
function changeFunc(){
// get value of select option first
var optionval = $('#selectBox').val();

// optionval should be 1 or 2 or 3
// now you can use ajax request after this and dispaly response where u want to show.

// your ajax request.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I am not aware of Ajax.if possible can you explain me how could be ajax request for my program.

Comment: @vinay: ist u tell me the detail u want to display product against filters? And u will fetch yur product by using mysql php

Comment: I dont knw about the policy of SO its better to explain here .. well update yur question first share your php code where u r using mysql query for getting data than it will be helpful

Comment: Actually i am developing a search engine. i didnt use php code.If i search by path then we get result.so for that i want to sort.[Here is My output]  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/c4uHx.jpg

Comment: My friend sorting will be effect to records or record will change as per sort it means a query will use to fetch the record against the sorting filter